# Ajax call cant reach controller after publish MVC

Tags: json, ajax, asp.net-mvc, http-get, internal-server-error

I have an MVC application developed in Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise.

Since some time, the application has started to generate errors in methods that have always worked before but have suddenly stopped working after I've published and moved over to the server.

Everything works clockwise in the development environment, but as soon as I've published it will be

> "Internal Server Error 500"

I've searched for answers to google and ended up on a lot of pages here on stack overflow. The answers I've found have I tested but not successful results.

So thought to hear if anyone here might see where it will be wrong.

My Code in the Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
    public virtual ActionResult GetLecturesDuringDay(string dateFromView)
    {
        var start = DateTime.Parse(dateFromView);
        var end = DateTime.Parse(dateFromView).AddDays(1);

        var scheduleModel = (EventHomeReturnModel)Session["ScheduleOnIndex"];

        var lecs = scheduleModel.WeekEvents.AllEvents.Where(e => e.Events.Any(ev => ev.Lecture == true && ev.StartDate >= start && ev.EndDate < end)).SelectMany(l => l.Events.Select(le => le.Id)).ToList();

        List<AttendanceLectureDisplayModel> returnModel = homeManager.GetAttendanceReportStartPageModel(start, lecs);

        return Json(returnModel, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

My code in the MVC view:

```
 <button onclick="generateAttendanceReportDay('@Model.DateMonday.ToShortDateString()')" >Närvarolistor</button>
```

My code in the javascript file:

```
 function generateAttendanceReportDay(date) {
 $.ajax({
        url: '/Home/GetLecturesDuringDay',
        type: 'get',
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { dateFromView: date },
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (lectures) {
 SOME CODE HERE...
 NEVER REACHING THIS CODE...
 }
 });
```

Please help

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A 500 error is just a generic message. It means something went wrong on the server side in the MVC app, but it's not specific enough to know how to solve it. You should check the server's event log.

Comment: Yes, i know. But couldnt find any errors in event viewer on the server. Im thinks that I search in the right folder.

Comment: Looked up what .net version the server has and it was 4.0 and we build the application in 4.5. But this should not be the problem because we have used 4.5 from start and not have this problem before.

Comment: well unless someone removed 4.5 from the server? BTW you know that only 4.0 will show up in IIS? To check if 4.5 is installed you have to go the Control Panel list of programs. Anyhow, any exceptions should be in the "Applications" log in the event viewer. Another tactic is to visit the site from the browser in the server itself via the "localhost" URL and it may show more detailed error messages there than when you access it remotely.